# Is it recommended to destroy UIViewController after finishing your work with them

Tags: ios, swift

I'm an Android developer, I started learning iOS development lately and I've been wondering about how to manage the UIViewControllers.

In Android, when you don't need an activity anymore, it is better to remove it from the application stack, for example a login screen is only needed when the user logs in, after that there is no need for that screen so it is better to destroy it and remove it from the stack, but what about iOS? Do you have to manage view controllers the same way as activities? or does the system automatically handle the views in the background?

It would be great if you can link some reference to read more about the way View-controllers are handled in the background, I'm trying to learn the best practices

Comment: The Swift uses ARC, so you don’t need to care about it. But I’m strongly recommend to read *[The Swift Programming Language](https://books.apple.com/us/book/the-swift-programming-language-swift-5-1-beta/id1002622538)*  book, it covers everything you need.

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer: No, let ARC handle it**

ARC handles the release from memory automatically when you pop a view from a navigation stack, so if you go "back" (pop) you normally don't need to worry about it.

But, sometimes you have a big navigation stacks with many different views with a lot of data/images/etc that will eat memory. In those cases you could separate your app into different flows and instead replace the root view controller of the main window with the new flow every time you want to change. The old flow should be released from memory automatically, unless its connected to another object (like a singleton).